# Creating Outlook object generates - Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm working on Excel-VBA code.

I'm getting run time error 429 on line -

```
Set mobjOLA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Code is given below -

```
Public Sub Test
    Dim mobjOLA as Object
    Set mobjOLA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End Sub
```

Comment: Set mobjOLA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") - in this line

Comment: Are you trying to call the function from Excel as a custom formula?

Comment: There is a button on workbook to update selected row. Calling  this function on click of it.

Comment: How do you pass the `strAppSubject` then?

Comment: It's a sub function that is getting called from another function

Comment: What kind of Office are you using? 64 or 32 bits?

Comment: 32 bit Microsoft office 365 ProPlus

Comment: If you only write a sub with 1 line in it - `Set a = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` would it work?

Comment: Sorry. Please give me an example.

Comment: simply delete all your code between `Function DeleteAppointmentItemBySubject ` and `End Function`, write this line and see whether it works.

Comment: Tried, not working

Comment: Cool, congrats. This is the essense of the question. Thus, I have updated your question to make it minimal.

Comment: Could you please tell me the solution now?

Comment: I do not know the solution. But you should try researching further. E.g., google the error and read the similar problems. And check your references.

Comment: Can you show how your updating the row?code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was mistake in system configuration. Reinstalling Office worked as a solution for me.